# For specific url 'www.example.com/mobile' I want url rewrite to another specific path: 'root_folder/mobile/index.html'

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I created a website in Symfony and the mobile version in Ionic.

Now all URLs are redirected to `/public/index.php`.

I want to add another URL rewrite in `.htaccess` to redirect all `www.example.com/mobile/*` to ionic app that is in the root folder `/mobile/index.html`.

I already tried to add this in `root_folder/mobile/.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobile/.*$
RewriteRule ^mobile/(.*)$ /mobile/index.html [R=301,NC,L]
```

My root_folder `.htaccess` is:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.ch$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpe?g|png|svg|webp|mp4|css|js|txt)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ public/index.php [L]

<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#/mobile/?#i">
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobile/.*$
    RewriteRule ^mobile/(.*)$ /mobile/index.html [R=301,NC,L]
</If>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobile/.*$
> RewriteRule ^mobile/(.*)$ /mobile/index.html [R=301,NC,L]
> ```

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against the URL-path relative to the directory that contains the `.htaccess` file. So, the above `RewriteRule` will never match when inside the `/mobile/.htaccess` file. Likewise, the *condition* will never be successful, since if the `.htaccess` is triggered then `/mobile/` must already be present in the URL-path.

This is also an external 301 redirect, not an internal rewrite. It needs to be an internal rewrite (just like the rewrite to `public/index.php` in the root).

However, presumably you also want static assets to be ignored and served directly, so you need exceptions for files (and optionally directories), just as you are doing in the root `.htaccess` file (when rewriting to `public/index.php`).

Try the following instead, in the `/mobile/.htaccess` file:

```
# /mobile/.htaccess

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.html [L]
```

You don't need to specify `/mobile` in any of the directives since the `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against the relative URL-path (as mentioned above) and the *substitution* string is (by default) relative to the directory that contains the `.htaccess` file.

By default, the mod_rewrite directives in the `/mobile/.htaccess` file completely override the directives in the parent `.htaccess` file. The directives in the parent `.htaccess` file are not even processed.

> ```
> <If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#/mobile/?#i">
>     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobile/.*$
>     RewriteRule ^mobile/(.*)$ /mobile/index.html [R=301,NC,L]
> </If>
> ```

You should remove this `<If>` block in the root `.htaccess` file. (It's not actually doing anything.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your explanation, it works now. I probably succeeded before in my attempts but on the desktop, ionic app redirects me to the homepage and I thought I didn't write .htaccess well.